# How to iteratively change RGB style in Show[Table[ListPlot[...]]] and create a Legend?

Tags: plotting, list-manipulation

I am trying to plot the outputs of a ListPlot with different colors for the 3 different cases and create a legend. I have tried with a simple `For` cycle, but then got that obviously that is not working because Mathematica correctly recognizes what is inside `ListPlot` as UNIQUE function, therefore my cycle is ineffective. How else can I do to obtain three different colors?

```
 fExact = Table[Table[Table[j i^2, {i, 10^k, 10^(k + 1), If[k >= 1, 10^k,10^(k 
 - 1)]}],{k, 0, 1, 1}], {j, {1, 2, 3}}];
 vector = Table[Table[Table[i, {i, 10^k, 10^(k + 1), If[k >= 1, 10^k, 10^(k 
 -1)]}],{k, 0, 1, 1}], {j, {1, 2, 3}}];
 Show[Table[Table[ListPlot[Transpose[{Transpose[{vector[[j]], fExact[[j]]}][[k]][[1]],
 Transpose[{vector[[j]], fExact[[j]]}][[k]][[2]]}], PlotStyle -> For[j = 1, j <= 3, j++, 
RGBColor[j, 0, 1]], 
Joined -> True], {k, 1, 1, 1}], {j, 1, 3, 1}], 
PlotRange -> {{0.001, 10}, {0.01, 10}}]
```

If I call:

```
try = Table[Table[ListPlot[Transpose[{Transpose[{vector[[j]], fExact[[j]]}][[k]][[1]], 
Transpose[{vector[[j]], fExact[[j]]}][[k]][[2]]}], Joined -> True, 
PlotStyle -> For[j = 0, j < 3, j++, RGBColor[j, 0, 1]]], {k, 1, 1,1}], {j, 1, 3, 1}]
```

I get:

[image]

Is there any way to access the `PlotStyle` option of the random try[[j]] element of try? In that way it should be easy to make a cycle and get what I want.

As for the legend, I tried `PlotLegends->{j}` but didn't work.

Comment: You can do `PlotStyle->RGBColor[j,0,1]`? (This isn't going to look very nice BTW.) I'd do something like `PlotStyle->ColorData[97][j]`.

Comment: @N.J.Evans why not nice? anyway, I 've just done what you suggested and still get that ALL the curves have the same colour following the first suggestion that you gave. Instead, the second one works!

Comment: rule number one for use of `For` is don't ever use it for anything (ever). If you insist on using it, realize It doesn't return anything.  In this case its really unclear what you even intend by by using the outside `Table` iterator as a loop variable inside a `For` loop.

Comment: @george2079 is it a mistake using the same iterator as a loop variable for `For`? Ok, I will avoid using `For`. However, I don't see any mistake in using that iterator twice; in fact, the answer from N.J.Evans works fine using `[j]` for `ColorData[97]`

Comment: NJEvans references `j`, he doesn't try to change it.  (Changing the table iterator is not an error, its just confusing.)

Comment: @george2079 oh now I see what you mean. I tried to change it rather than referencing it because, when using `PlotStyle->RGBColor[j]`, I saw no effect. Why isn't the iterator working in that case?

Comment: `RGBColor` needs three arguments.  Other things you can do for simple cases is like this `{Red, Green, Blue}[[j]]` , or `Hue[j/4]` .

Comment: @george2079 sorry, I meant I used `PlotStyle->RGBColor[j,0,1]` and didn't get it. Could you help me figuring out why? The other ones are clear.

Comment: `RGBColor` arguments need to be in range `0-1` so `RGBColor[j/4, 0, 1]` may work (Although the colors will all be shades of purple so may not look very different ).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/57837/discussion-between-andrea-g-and-george2079).